# Terraform: Interpolation could be replaced by HCL2 expression

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

When I try to use interpolation syntax like this:

```
vpc_id     = "${aws_vpc.prod-vpc.id}"
```

I get the suggestion in IntelliJ that "Interpolation could be replaced by HCL2 expression", so if I change the line into this:

```
 vpc_id     = "aws_vpc.prod-vpc.id"
```

and issue terraform apply, I get:

```
C:\tf_ptojects\aws\subnet>terraform apply -auto-approve
aws_subnet.prod-subnet: Creating...
aws_vpc.prod-vpc: Creating...
aws_vpc.prod-vpc: Creation complete after 2s [id=vpc-0cfb27255522bdf15]

Error: error creating subnet: InvalidVpcID.NotFound: The vpc ID 'aws_vpc.prod-vpc.id' does not exist
        status code: 400, request id: dab3fb03-424d-4bf2-ace6-bef93a94ee9c
```

If I re-apply interpolation syntax and run terraform apply again, then the resources get deployed but I get the warning in Terraform, saying that interpolation-only expressions are deprecated:

```
 Warning: Interpolation-only expressions are deprecated

  on main.tf line 16, in resource "aws_subnet" "prod-subnet":
  16:   vpc_id     = "${aws_vpc.prod-vpc.id}"
```

So TF is discouraging the use of interpolation syntax, yet issues an error if it's not used. Is it some kind of bug or something?

```
C:\tf_ptojects\aws\subnet>terraform -version
Terraform v0.14.4
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.25.0
```

Entire TF code for reference:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-central-1"
}


resource "aws_vpc" "prod-vpc" {
  cidr_block = "10.100.0.0/16"

  tags = {
    name = "production vpc"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "prod-subnet" {
  cidr_block = "10.100.1.0/24"
  vpc_id     = "aws_vpc.prod-vpc.id"

  tags = {
    name = "prod-subnet"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to get the id without using double quotes `vpc_id     = aws_vpc.prod-vpc.id` because you are getting vpc id from the resource.
If you use the double quotes, it will be considered as a string and no evaluation will be done, and terraform will consider `"aws_vpc.prod-vpc.id"` as the id.

This is the corrected code:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-central-1"
}


resource "aws_vpc" "prod-vpc" {
  cidr_block = "10.100.0.0/16"

  tags = {
    name = "production vpc"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "prod-subnet" {
  cidr_block = "10.100.1.0/24"
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.prod-vpc.id

  tags = {
    name = "prod-subnet"
  }
}
```

I had tested the above code snippet and it is working perfectly fine.

Comment: What happens in a case like `base64encode("${local.some_variable}")`, where the function should take a string argument, but Pycharm/Terraform suggests converting to HCL expression `base64encode(local.some_variable)`  even though `local.some_variable` is a json object.